# OpenGL Drawing quads in minecraft display weirdly

Tags: java, opengl, minecraft

Im trying to draw some quads in minecraft but this is the problem im having: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pgfA.jpg but it should draw triangles on each sides so there should be 4 triangles in total, I dont know why this isnt working.

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glDepthMask(false);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GL11.glColor4f(0F, 0.5F, 0.8F, 1F);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX + 1, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ + 1);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX - 1, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ - 1);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX - 1, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ + 1);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX + 1, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ - 1);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glDepthMask(true);
GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Please post the code directly in the question (each line prepended by 4 spaces).

Comment: I tried that, it didnt work and looked horrible.

Comment: I edited your post. You could make the code more legible by using `glTranslate(-RenderManager.renderPosX, -RenderManager.renderPosY, -RenderManager.renderPosZ)` instead of applying the translation manually on each vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably disable face culling: `GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);` Your triangles might have the wrong orientation, so you only see the back faces. Another solution would be to reorient the triangles (e.g. by swapping the first and second vertex), but since you use transparency you probably want to render both front and back faces.

Side note: I don't know why you're using GL_QUADS if you want to render triangles. So here's the first quad you posted:

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX + 1, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ + 1);
GL11.glVertex3d(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY + ep.height + 0.5D - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ);
GL11.glEnd();
```

The equivalent code using glTranslate and GL_TRIANGLES would be:

```
GL11.glTranslated(ep.posX - RenderManager.renderPosX, ep.posY - RenderManager.renderPosY, ep.posZ - RenderManager.renderPosZ );
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
GL11.glVertex3d(0, ep.height + 0.5D, 0);
GL11.glVertex3d(1, 0, 0);
GL11.glVertex3d(0, 0, 1);
GL11.glEnd();
```

Also note that you don't need to call `glBegin/glEnd` for each triangle, you can simply call `glVertex3d` 3*n times to render n triangles.

Comment: Thanks, You helped me fix my code and make it look neater! Is there a way I can rep you or something?

Comment: @user2487095 Just accepting the answer and maybe upvoting it is fine, thank you. Glad I could help. :)