# Minecraft Modding ".bindTexture" doesn't work

Tags: java, events, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I had a problem programming my first Minecraft Mod.

Here is the source code:

**Events.java:**

```
public class Events { 
     @SubscribeEvent
     public void onRenderGameOverlay(RenderGameOverlayEvent event) {
          if(!event.isCancelable() && event.type == ElementType.EXPERIENCE && !Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.capabilities.isCreativeMode) {
               int posX = event.resolution.getScaledWidth() / 2 + 10;
               int posY = event.resolution.getScaledHeight() - 48;
               Minecraft.getMinecraft().renderEngine.bindTexture(new ResourceLocation("tc:textures/gui/thermo-icon.png"));
               Minecraft.getMinecraft().ingameGUI.drawTexturedModalRect(posX + 9, posY + 3, 0, 9, 71, 3);
          }
     }
}
```

So, my problem is that in Minecraft it shows me this:
[image: NOTE THE RED ELLIPSE]

Note the red ellipse (I added it with GIMP), inside it there is a black rectangle (I haven't added it with GIMP)... it is too small and without texture...

I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi41BAlRjtE), but still not working...

Any solution, please?

UPDATE - - - - - -

Thanks all guys for help, I understood that height = 3 pixel is too small... But now I've one more problem...

[image: Here is it]

The light grey rectangle in the center, should be a
square, and the black part should be a "circle".

Does anyone know the cause of the wrong proportions? Thanks!

Comment: Aren't mods illegal?

Comment: Almost all single player mods are legal.
Except if they help you obtain any payed-for part of the game for free/money to another person. @MathewsMathai

Comment: Okay. Got it. Is minecraft designed using java?

Comment: Yes! Minecraft is designed with Java @MathewsMathai

Comment: You were using "ScaledHeight" and "ScaledWidth".   Its obviously scaling based on your view port or some thing.    The minecraft gui does scaling and all sorts of things (like messing with colors if you don't disable the lighting).    You probably want to used something like the Tessellator.  http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Tessellator  That should help you draw in absolute space.   For circles, those are harder.   Check out this circle helper stuff : http://www.buckaroopopcorn.com/2010/12/how-to-draw-circle-in-square-world.html

Comment: I haven't understood at all how to use Tessellator... can you help me? @LawfulEvil

Comment: Seems like a different question.  What code did you try and what did it do?  May want to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Eclipse signals error when I write "Tessellator.getInstance()" so I can't try the method you wrote... Do you recommend me to start a new question about this topic? @LawfulEvil

Comment: Yes, Exactly.   There are other ways to draw (aside from Tessellator) so others may come up with other options.    I thought the instance thing was "Tessellator tessellator = Tessellator.instance;"    Here is another question someone asked about minecraft drawing on SO.  Maybe if you search around you'll find some good examples.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252166/opengl-drawing-quads-in-minecraft-display-weirdly  Also check out the tutorial : http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Gui_Overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too small?

What size were you expecting?

```
drawTexturedModalRect(posX + 9, posY + 3, 0, 9, 71, 3);
```

Is it not 71 pixels long and 3 tall... just what you provided?   Its hard to tell.  Maybe the texture is working but you are offseting it by 9 pixels(when you only draw 3 pixels of it), but it looks like you are using bindTexture wrong.   It takes an int returned from getTexture.

```
int i = mc.renderEngine.getTexture("/Items/GUI/mixer.png");
GL11.glColor4f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
mc.renderEngine.bindTexture(i);
```

There is a nice wiki / tutorial on doing the sort of mods you are doing that might help : http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Gui_Overlay#Mod_Code

Comment: Thanks man! Look at the update I made in the question, please